# Is this the proper way to select the previous and next record given an ID for the current record?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to run a LINQ query which will return 3 rows (The current record, Previous record, and the next record relative to the current record. ProductID is my autogenerated identity column.

Currently i'm doing this with a Union LINQ statement but I'm not sure if there is a better or a more efficient way to accomplish the same task.

Here's what I got:

```
var ProductID = 10;

var Results = (from p in DB.Products
where p.ProductID == ProductID - 1 //Previous record.
select new Product
{
    ProductID = p.ProductID,
    ProductTitle = p.ProductTitle,
    Views = p.Views,
}).Union(from p in DB.Products
where p.ProductID == ProductID //Current record
select new Product
{
    ProductID = p.ProductID,
    ProductTitle = p.ProductTitle,
    Views = p.Views,
}).Union(from p in DB.Products
where p.ProductID == ProductID + 1 //Next record.
select new Product
{
    ProductID = p.ProductID,
    ProductTitle = p.ProductTitle,
    Views = p.Views,
});
```

This should return 3 rows for ProductID 9, ProductID 10, ProductID 11. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach can be rewritten more shortly like this:

```
var ProductID = 10;

var Results = (from p in DB.Products
where p.ProductID >= ProductID - 1 &&
      p.ProductID <= ProductID + 1
select new Product
{
   ProductID = p.ProductID,
   ProductTitle = p.ProductTitle,
   Views = p.Views,
});
```

But note, this will return what you need only if none of the records corresponding to the specified productIDs have been deleted from the Products table.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I would use this approach:
it has the benefit of working where Ids are missing in the range.   A brave man assumes all Ids are accounted for and present.

```
 var currAndNext = Context.Set<TPoco>()
                  .Where<TPoco>(t=>t.id == id)
                  .OrderBy(t=>t.id)
                  .Skip(0)
                  .Take(2);
 var prev = Context.Set<TPoco>()
                  .Where<TPoco>(t=>t.id == id)
                  .OrderByDescending(t=>t.id)
                  .Skip(1)
                  .Take(1);
```

Comment: I don't understand. First you put a where clause on the ID column (which will leave only one record), and then you order and skip and take. That would still only leave you the current... What am I missing?

Comment: this is the correct one, as we cannot just assume that Id's will be in range. This is best practice.

Comment: Copied from an answer that should have been a comment: as a minor change to it, I used `.Where<TPoco>(t=>t.id <= id)` and `.Where<TPoco>(t=>t.id >= id)` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

GwynBleidd proposed a good solution, however you can also specify a list of IDs, in your case like this:

```
var ids = new[] {ProductID - 1, ProcuctID, ProductID + 1};
```

And use it in the where clause

```
var Results = from p in DB.Products
              where ids.Contains(p.ProductID)
              select new Product
              {
                 ProductID = p.ProductID,
                 ProductTitle = p.ProductTitle,
                 Views = p.Views,
              };
```

I think this is more versatile and EF will translate it to `WHERE [ProductID] IN (...)`, which the query execution planner can handle quite well.

Comment: You've missprinted the method name. It should be ids.Contains(...) :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would solve the problem -- avoiding the use of +1,-1.

In my case, I was trying to show the previous/next **published** blog posts. The +1,-1 wouldn't work if the next/prev blog post was **unpublished**. Not to mention the possibility of Ids not always being consecutive.

In your case, you may not want to show the out of stock products.

```
var products = db.Products.Where(x => x.Quantity > 0).OrderBy(x => x.ProductId).ToList();

var previous = products.LastOrDefault(x => x.ProductId < id),
var next = products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductId > id)
```

This will return the previous and next products with the `ProductId` closest to your starting `id`.

Note: the `.OrderBy(x => x.ProductId)` isn't necessary if your list is already in order.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my take on this:

```
await using var context = new CsuContext(this._csuContextOptions);

var offenseLogs =
  context.OffenseLogs ?? throw new Exception("SQL Connection Error");

var last = await offenseLogs.OrderByDescending(log => log.Id)
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);

if (id == 0) id = last.Id;

var currentAndNext = offenseLogs.Where(log => log.Id >= id)
                                .OrderBy(log => log.Id)
                                .Take(2);

var current = await currentAndNext.FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                                  .ConfigureAwait(false);

var next = await currentAndNext.Skip(1)
                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                               .ConfigureAwait(false);

var previous = await offenseLogs.Where(log => log.Id <= id)
                                .OrderByDescending(log => log.Id)
                                .Take(2)
                                .Skip(1)
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                                .ConfigureAwait(false);

var first = await offenseLogs.OrderBy(log => log.Id)
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                             .ConfigureAwait(false);

var entry = this._mapper.Map<OffenseLog, OffenseLogDto>(current ??
                                                        throw new
                                                          Exception($"Could not find entry with id: {id}"));
entry.Next     = next?.Id;
entry.Previous = previous?.Id;
entry.First    = first.Id != entry.Id ? first.Id : null;
entry.Last     = last.Id != entry.Id ? last.Id : null;

return entry;
```